# Comparing HTML variable to a CSV item with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv

So I want to compare a user's checked out item to a csv file. The checkout item comes from the div class item-options, and I want to be able to look at that and then check if the name is in the csv file. At the moment the script is not detecting when a correct item is in the user's basket.

[example, the item is in the csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dr5PC.png)

HTML

```
 <div class="item-options">
             <!--START: itemnamelink--><a href="product.asp?itemid=[ITEM_CATALOGID]">[ITEM_NAME]</a><!--END: itemnamelink-->
             <!--START: itemnamenolink--><span id="Span1">[ITEM_NAME]</span><!--END: itemnamenolink-->
             <!--START: itemoptions-->
             <br />
             <a href="#" onclick="toggleProdOptions('opt[ITEM_ID]')">View/Hide options</a><br />
             <div id="opt[ITEM_ID]" name="opt[ITEM_ID]" style="display:none;">[OPTIONS]</div>
             <!--END: itemoptions-->
             <!--START: recurring_frequency-->
             <br />
             This item will Autoship every <strong>[recurring_frequency]</strong>
             <!--END: recurring_frequency--></div>
         </div>
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "assets/exports/pipe.csv",

  success: function(data) {

    var itemToStore = document.getElementsByClassName("item-options");

    for (var i = 0; i < itemToStore.length; i++) {
      var name = itemToStore [i].innerText;
      console.log("Name: " + name);

    // Remove \n and split by ,
    var pipeList = data.split('\r\n').map(function(row){return row.split(',')});
    // Array of arrays like be generated
      for(var i = 0; i < pipeList.length; i++){
          if ($.inArray(name, pipeList[i]) != -1) {          

              console.log('value is Array!');
              }
          else {
            console.log("it is not");
          }
      }

    }
  }
});

});
```

CSV file

[CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irkwO.png)

[image: console.log(pipeList)]

Comment: What do you get in `console.log(pipeList );`

Comment: Updated my OP with a snippet of it

Comment: Why there is an extra double quotes? ""1 1/2"" 3m lenghts- ....

Answer (score 0):

You are checking the name `1 1/2" 3m lenghts - White Class D`

to `1 1/2"" 3m lenghts - White Class D"`

which obviously returns false.

```
if ($.inArray(name, pipeList[i]) != -1) { .. }
```

Also add `dataType: "text"` in $.ajax options

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "assets/exports/pipe.csv",
  dataType: "text"
```

Comment: how can i remove the 2 " ?

Comment: @JohnDoi is that in original csv file?